# Separating data in name field so it can be filtered in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, filter

I have some information that I want to filter by some of the fields under the primary name field for ex: `"gs_substation"` or `"gs_feeder_number"`. But they are unable to be filtered using an expression, only the number in the name field is filterable.

How can I separate the fields into their own fields so I can filter them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just added the attribute table image

Comment: I'm not clear from your screenshots where these "gs_" fields are coming from. Can you clarify?

Comment: They are from point or string data imported from shapefile. Any poing of line clicked shows the data as such. The info I got from the source said the data has been in multiple softwares. ARC, saved to KMZ, KMZ back to ARC, ARC to a third party software, finally back to KMZ.

Comment: I'd suggest posting a sample of data somewhere, if that's an option, and linking in the question (or post some data directly in the question). It makes it a lot more likely that someone will be able to answer